# Remote Debugging Azure App Service Site Fails

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging

I'm trying to debug an ASPNET Core/EF Core website hosted on Azure. When I try to attach the debugger in VS 2015, via Cloud Explorer, I get this error message:

[image: cloud explorer error]

Yet when I check the site in the Azure portal, it sure seems like it's 32 bit and set to enable remote debugging:

[image: portal description]

So what am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Portal setting controls the bitness of the IIS w3wp process. But ASP.NET Core runs in its own process, so that setting has no effect on it. Instead, what determines whether your .NET Core process runs as 32 or 64 bit is how you publish it.

Given that apparently your Core project is published as 64 bit, you might want to try switching the Portal setting to 64 bit. This will affect the debugger MSVCMON.exe process, which should then allow you to attach.

Comment: Thank you, David! I can now connect to my Azure app to debug it. I would never in a million years have realized that I had to make that change.

Comment: BTW, while I can now attach, I can't set breakpoints to be hit. When I try to set a breakpoint, I get a warning that "no symbols are available", and I end up with an empty red breakpoint circle. What's weird is that the PDB files are up on the Azure site. Any further advice?

Comment: The VS Modules window can be helpful to figure out those issues.